Troubleshooting Async Method Issues in Unit Tests: Resolving FirstOrDefaultAsync() Failures
Problem with Testing FirstOrDefaultAsync() in My Example Code
I have the method below where I'm fetching the user ID by username, and I've written tests for it. However, the tests are not working when using FirstOrDefaultAsync(). If I switch to FirstOrDefault(), the tests work fine. Here's the code:
Method Being Tested:
public async Task<int> GetUserId(string userName)
{
   return await _unitofWork.Repository<UserEntity>().Entities
                              .Where(u => u.UserName == userName)
                              .Select(i => i.Id)
                              .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}

Test Code:
[Fact]
public async Task GetUserIdTests()
{
    //Arrange
    var userEntity= new List<UserEntity>
    {
        new UserEntity
        {
            UserName = "testuser", Id = 1
        }
    };
    var repositoryMock = new Mock<IGenericRepository<UserEntity>>();
    repositoryMock.Setup(r => r.Entities).Returns(new TestAsyncEnumerable<UserEntity>(systemUsers).AsQueryable());
    _unitOfWorkMock.Setup(u => u.Repository<UserEntity>()).Returns(repositoryMock.Object);

    var service= new service(_userContextMock.Object,_vaultServiceMock.Object);
    //Act
    var result = await service.GetUserId("testuser");
    //Assert
    Assert.NotEqual(0, result);

}

Issue:
This is just an example I created to test the FirstOrDefaultAsync() method, but it is not working. The test works correctly when using FirstOrDefault() but fails with FirstOrDefaultAsync().
Supporting Code:
Here is the TestAsyncEnumerable class that I'm using to support async operations in the test:
public class TestAsyncEnumerable<T> : EnumerableQuery<T>, IAsyncEnumerable<T>, IQueryable<T>
 {
     public TestAsyncEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> enumerable) : base(enumerable) { }
     public TestAsyncEnumerable(Expression expression) : base(expression) { }

     public IAsyncEnumerator<T> GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
     {
         return new TestAsyncEnumerator<T>(this.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator());
     }

     IAsyncEnumerator<T> IAsyncEnumerable<T>.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     {
         return GetAsyncEnumerator(cancellationToken);
     }

     IQueryProvider IQueryable.Provider => new TestAsyncQueryProvider<T>(this);
 }

 public class TestAsyncEnumerator<T> : IAsyncEnumerator<T>
 {
     private readonly IEnumerator<T> _inner;

     public TestAsyncEnumerator(IEnumerator<T> inner)
     {
         _inner = inner;
     }

     public ValueTask DisposeAsync()
     {
         _inner.Dispose();
         return ValueTask.CompletedTask;
     }

     public ValueTask<bool> MoveNextAsync()
     {
         return new ValueTask<bool>(_inner.MoveNext());
     }

     public T Current => _inner.Current;
 }

 public class TestAsyncQueryProvider<T> : IAsyncQueryProvider
 {
     private readonly IQueryProvider _inner;

     public TestAsyncQueryProvider(IQueryProvider inner)
     {
         _inner = inner;
     }

     public IQueryable CreateQuery(Expression expression)
     {
         return new TestAsyncEnumerable<T>(expression);
     }

     public IQueryable<TElement> CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression)
     {
         return new TestAsyncEnumerable<TElement>(expression);
     }

     public object Execute(Expression expression)
     {
         return _inner.Execute(expression);
     }

     public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)
     {
         return _inner.Execute<TResult>(expression);
     }

     public TResult ExecuteAsync<TResult>(Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     {
         return Execute<TResult>(expression);
     }

     public IAsyncEnumerable<TResult> ExecuteAsync<TResult>(Expression expression)
     {
         return new TestAsyncEnumerable<TResult>(expression);
     }
 }

Question:
What might be causing the test to fail when using FirstOrDefaultAsync()? Is there something wrong with how I've implemented the TestAsyncEnumerable class or how the async test is set up?
**Error:**
Message: 
System.ArgumentException : Argument expression is not valid

  Stack Trace: 
IQueryProvider.Execute[TElement](Expression expression)
TestAsyncQueryProvider`1.Execute[TResult](Expression expression) line 72
TestAsyncQueryProvider`1.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken) line 78
EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ExecuteAsync[TSource,TResult](MethodInfo operatorMethodInfo, IQueryable`1 source, Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ExecuteAsync[TSource,TResult](MethodInfo operatorMethodInfo, IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)


Now that you've changed the question... where does TestAsyncEnumerable come from? (And what is SystemUser vs UserEntity?) It would be really helpful if you'd provide a [mcve].

This question is similar to: How to mock an async repository with Entity Framework Core. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You should be using ReturnsAsync

@beautifulcoder: Isn't that aimed at async methods returning a Task<T> or similar? There's a difference between an asynchronous method, and a property returning an "asynchronously-consumable" collection. I may be missing something, of course.

@JonSkeet you are right, didn't realize it was a property

@JonSkeet Added TestAsyncEnumerable code

I have updated question and added supporting code

If you remove Moq from the picture (and ASP.NET Core etc) and just have a console app which creates the list, and uses FirstOrDefaultAsync directly on that, does that work? (Again, reducing this to minimal code would really help.)

(Sorry, I meant "creates the list, creates a TestAsyncEnumerable from that, and then uses .Where(...).Select(...).FirstOrDefaultAsync()")

However, the tests are not working when using FirstOrDefaultAsync(). How specifically are they not working?

I resolved the issue by implementing the following approach:
AsyncHelper Class: I created an AsyncHelper class that contains the necessary implementations for handling asynchronous queries.
The code for the classes is as follows:
internal class TestAsyncQueryProvider<TEntity> : IAsyncQueryProvider
{
    private readonly IQueryProvider _innerQueryProvider;

    internal TestAsyncQueryProvider(IQueryProvider inner)
    {
        _innerQueryProvider = inner;
    }

    public IQueryable CreateQuery(Expression expression)
    {
        return new TestAsyncEnumerable<TEntity>(expression);
    }

    public IQueryable<TElement> CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression)
    {
        return new TestAsyncEnumerable<TElement>(expression);
    }

    public object Execute(Expression expression) => _innerQueryProvider.Execute(expression);

    public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression) => _innerQueryProvider.Execute<TResult>(expression);

    TResult IAsyncQueryProvider.ExecuteAsync<TResult>(Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Type expectedResultType = typeof(TResult).GetGenericArguments()[0];
        object? executionResult = ((IQueryProvider)this).Execute(expression);

        return (TResult)typeof(Task).GetMethod(nameof(Task.FromResult))
            .MakeGenericMethod(expectedResultType)
            .Invoke(null, new[] { executionResult });
    }
}

internal class TestAsyncEnumerable<T> : EnumerableQuery<T>, IAsyncEnumerable<T>, IQueryable<T>
{
    public TestAsyncEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
        : base(enumerable)
    { }

    public TestAsyncEnumerable(Expression expression)
        : base(expression)
    { }

    IQueryProvider IQueryable.Provider => new TestAsyncQueryProvider<T>(this);

    public IAsyncEnumerator<T> GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
        => new TestAsyncEnumerator<T>(this.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator());
}

internal class TestAsyncEnumerator<T> : IAsyncEnumerator<T>
{
    private readonly IEnumerator<T> _enumerator;

    public TestAsyncEnumerator(IEnumerator<T> inner)
    {
        _enumerator = inner;
    }

    public T Current => _enumerator.Current;

    public ValueTask DisposeAsync() => new(Task.Run(() => _enumerator.Dispose()));

    public ValueTask<bool> MoveNextAsync() => new(_enumerator.MoveNext());
}

Test Modification: I then modified the unit test to utilize these new classes, ensuring that the asynchronous query execution is correctly handled within the mock setup.
The updated test code is as follows:
[Fact]
public async Task GetUserIdTests()
{
    // Arrange
    var userEntity = new List<UserEntity>
    {
        new UserEntity
        {
            UserName = "testuser",
            Id = 1
        }
    }.AsQueryable();

    var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<UserEntity>>();

    mockSet.As<IAsyncEnumerable<UserEntity>>()
        .Setup(m => m.GetAsyncEnumerator(default))
        .Returns(new AsyncHelper.TestAsyncEnumerator<UserEntity>(userEntity.GetEnumerator()));

    mockSet.As<IQueryable<UserEntity>>()
        .Setup(m => m.Provider)
        .Returns(new AsyncHelper.TestAsyncQueryProvider<UserEntity>(userEntity.Provider));

    mockSet.As<IQueryable<UserEntity>>()
        .Setup(m => m.Expression)
        .Returns(userEntity.Expression);

    mockSet.As<IQueryable<UserEntity>>()
        .Setup(m => m.ElementType)
        .Returns(userEntity.ElementType);

    mockSet.As<IQueryable<UserEntity>>()
        .Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator())
        .Returns(() => userEntity.GetEnumerator());

    var repositoryMock = new Mock<IGenericRepository<UserEntity>>();
    repositoryMock.Setup(r => r.Entities).Returns(mockSet.Object);

    _unitOfWorkMock.Setup(u => u.Repository<UserEntity>()).Returns(repositoryMock.Object);

    var service = new Service(_userContextMock.Object, _vaultServiceMock.Object);

    // Act
    var result = await service.GetUserId("testuser");

    // Assert
    Assert.NotEqual(0, result);
}


This is either an issue in TestAsyncEnumerable or in the EF code that does stuff behind the scenes with it. It's not specific to ASP.NET Core or mocking.
I copy/pasted your TestAsyncEnumerable code into a new console app, then wrote the following minimal example:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var list = new List<string> { "ab", "cde", "fgh", "ij" };

var query = new TestAsyncEnumerable<string>(list);
var first = await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync();

Console.WriteLine(first);

... and it failed with the same exception. (Originally I included Select and Where clauses, but they're not needed to reproduce the issue.)
It's unclear where TestAsyncEnumerable came from (whether it's home-grown or came from a blog post or similar) but it looks like that's the thing you need to fix.
